# Retreive Azure usage cost using the cli

Tags: azure, az

I'd like to retrieve the current cost of my azure usage using the cli. On the Azure UI I can easily see the total costs in *Subscriptions*:

[image: azure subscription list with cost]

The closest I can get to retrieving costs is using the `az consumption usage list` command:

```
az consumption usage list --debug --end-date 2019-07-19 --start-date 2019-07-01
```

This command gives me an extremely fine-grained list of the services I've been using along with their costs. All I want is the simple sum.

I'm wondering if there is a way to directly retrieve the totals?

Comment: Hi zoltanctoth,
have you solved this problem? I'm facing it just now

Comment: @Giova I have an ugly hack which gives us an approximate. Far from ideal, but serves our purposes at the time. Here you go: https://gist.github.com/zoltanctoth/eb3ff39efe779a7790e94f3b387827f7

Comment: I created a cli tool to extract the cost that might help you https://github.com/mivano/azure-cost-cli